# Berryboot equivalent for a x86 system

Tags: linux, bootloader

Berryboot is a pretty neat pre-boot environment that lets you install one of several pre-selected images to your raspi. It uses VNC for picking your boot options.

So basically what I need is

1. A preboot menu accessable remotely — with a GUI and VNC support.
2. The option to pick a installer option from a bunch of preloaded ISOs or images
3. Ideally the ability to control the installer over VNC as well. If nothing else, support for RH based systems and Debian/Ubuntu based Linux distros. Failing that, I should be able to use a local kickstart file or one that is pre-integrated into the iso. [Looks like fedora has that as a boot option](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/VNC_Whitepaper-installation.html) so that's a start
4. The ability to fire up this environment from a running system and/or have a small, configurable window of opportunity to activate this remotely.

I wouldn't mind sticking this on a persistent, separate partition ala berryboot or if this ran off a USB drive.

Comment: Looks like fedora does a vnc boot option http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Installation_Guide/VNC_Whitepaper-installation.html and has for ages